# Exceptions w/QtConcurrent::Exception and boost::exception

Tags: boost, exception, qt4

I want to use an exception hierarchy where the base exception class derives from `boost::exception` so that I can get the nice and useful diagnostic information that that class has to offer **and** `QtConcurrent::Exception` so that I can throw my exceptions across threads.

Hence, my base exception class looks like:

```
class MyException : public QtConcurrent::Exception, public boost::exception
{
public:
    MyException() { };
    virtual ~MyException() throw() { }

    // required by QtConcurrent::Exception to be implemented
    virtual void raise() const { throw *this; }
    virtual MyException* clone() const { return new MyException(*this); }
};
```

Per `QtConcurrent::Exception`'s documentation, `raise()` and `clone()` must be implemented in any class derived from `QtConcurrent::Exception`. So, the rest of my code may look something like:

```
void foo()
{
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(MyException());
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch (const MyException& me)
    {
        std::cerr << boost::diagnostic_information(me);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, using the `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION()` macro causes the following compilation error:

> error C2555: 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl::clone':
>   overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant
>   from 'MyException::clone'

I am not entirely sure what this error is telling me (my fault, not the errors, I'm sure!).

If I instead use `throw MyException();` the code compiles just fine. As I mentioned above, I'd like to use `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION()` so that I get the diagnostic information in my exceptions.

I know that one possible work-around could be another class derived from just `QtConcurrent::Exception` that has a boost::exception member, essentially a container for the actual error. But if possible, I would like to continue to have the `MyException` class inherit from both `QtConcurrent::Exception` and boost::exception.

Can someone offer some insight into what the error is saying? Is there any way to accomplish what I want?